# how to adjust the tickposition or 'x' axis on areapline highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The situation with my char is that currently the tick marks are positioned according to my "tickposition" paramenter, they displayed what I want but the problem is that for example the tick mark on '50' should be right on the middle of the chart, below the 50% bubble. So my chart looks off center.

I am not sure if the type of chart I am using is the correct one or how to approach this problem. I am super new on Highcharts.

Here is what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjwh/hu1t8159/15/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
       tickPositions: [250, 500, 750, 1000],
        min: 0,
        max: 900,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.value / 10;
            }
        },
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        allowDecimals: false,
        floor : 0,
        ceiling: 200,
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        lineColor: 'transparent',
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
         labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    chart: {
        events: {
            redraw: function () {
                var chart = this,
                    point = chart.series[1].points[0];
                if(chart.customLabel) {
                    chart.customLabel.attr({
                        x: point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 25,
                        y: point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 65,
                        anchorX: point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, 
                        anchorY: point.plotY + chart.plotTop
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'areaspline',
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
       data: [
            [0, 1],
            [210, 1],
            [225, 2],
            [372,108],
            [378,112],
            [387, 118],
            [396, 122],
            [403, 125],
            [433, 130],             
            [450, 129],
            [460, 126],
            [472, 122],
            [479, 118],
            [486, 114],
            [495,108],
            [502,102],
            [504,100],
            [510, 94],
            [514, 89],
            [518, 85],
            [522, 81],
            [526, 76],
            [529, 72],
            [534, 67],
            [541, 59],
            [548, 51],
            [556, 43],
            [566, 34],             
            [583, 22],
            [593, 17],
            [612, 9],
            [621, 6],
            [626, 5],
            [635, 3],
            [642, 2],
            [651, 1],
            [870, 1],
            [1000, 1]              
        ],
        zoneAxis: 'x',
        zones: [{
            value: 430,
            color: '#18d1ba'
        }, {
            color: '#74e3d6'
        }]
    }, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [
            [430, 130]
        ],
        marker: {
            radius: 8,
            symbol: 'circle',
            fillColor: '#fff',
            lineColor: '#09f',
            lineWidth: 3
        }
    }]
}, function (chart) { // on complete
    var point = chart.series[1].points[0];
    chart.customLabel = chart.renderer.label('50%', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 25, point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 65, 'callout', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop)
        .css({
        color: '#09f',
        fontSize: '18px'
    })
        .attr({
        'stroke-width': 3,
        stroke: '#09f',
        fill: '#fff',
        padding: 8,
        r: 5,
        zIndex: 6
    })
        .add();
});
```

});

This is a picture of the desired chart, please note the position of the 'x' positions or tickmarks. 
http://claudiawong.ca/test/example.png

Would anyone happen to give me an example of what to change, ideally an example on the form of a jsfiddle would be really helpful.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: I don't understand how the "50" label can be under the peak of your graph when the peak occurs at x-value 433 in a range of 0 to 1000. It's not the middle of the range. You can always move it by just setting the tickposition to that value, and rename it in your formatter, but I don't think that makes any sense either.

Comment: Yeah, well to be honest I do agree that it does not make sense however that was the chart that was given to me.  Any help on achieving this would be appreciate it

Comment: Could you specify where the labels should be placed in relation to data? You could add new labels or text using Highcharts' renderer - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text

Comment: According to the image posted, "100%" is set according to something other than the max value.  You need to know what 100% is, and calculate your 25/50/75 % values based on that.  Those calculated values (and the 100% value) are what you need to supply to your tickPositions array.  (in your case, you know what 50% is, so you can calculate everything from that...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

1) You know, in your example, that 50% is 430. You can determine from that what 25, 75, and 100% are.

2) You can set the values of those percentages as your tickPositions array.

3) You will need to map the values to the % that you want to display in your labels

A very quick and dirty example:

```
var x100 = 860;
var x75  = (x100 * .75);
var x50  = (x100 * .5 );
var x25  = (x100 * .25);

var vals = {};
vals[x100] = '100';
vals[x75 ] = '75';
vals[x50 ] = '50';
vals[x25 ] = '25';
```

You can then use this object in your label formatter to display the correct value.

Example:http://jsfiddle.net/hu1t8159/18/

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense now! Exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: how would I go about making the percentage bubble dynamic? Calculating the X position is easy cuz it could be similar to how you did it on your example, the challenge I am having is on the Y position as it would have to be along the curve line......I think there may be a math function to even create that curve but I am basically using x,y coordinates I got from Illustrator......any info/tips?

Comment: You would have to either use the same calculations that were used to build the curve in the first place, or loop through the data looking for a matching x value, and use the corresponding y value.  If there are no matches, find the 2 x values that your point falls between, and split the difference for the y.

Comment: Example of looping through the data here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/hu1t8159/22/  This example also uses the built in datalables property for the callout instead of a custom label - eliminates need for redraw event function